# How to prevent tapping on notification with universal link in ios app to only open app without the in app browser? onesignal expo react native plink

Tags: react-native, expo, onesignal

I am using onesignal for the app built expo react-native. The Android is working fine with the universal link. For ios the notification is being received but when tapping on it the app opens and on top an in-app brower with the link opens. I have spent hours trying to identify the issue. Any clue?

App is using navigationcontainer library so also followed the navigationcontainer instruction exactly from the instructions https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/.